# Import excel sheet into datatable without Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB

Tags: c#, .net, excel, windows-8

I want to import data from excel sheet (only single sheet) to datatable. Then use that datatable via grid to show data.
First of all, I use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB` to importing but it's useless on computer's which don't have access database engine.

I don't want to install access database engine on every computer(client system's).

> Is there any solution to doing this without access database engine?

ps. I exactly need to convert sheet to datatable.

Comment: Which version of Excel ? You can try with ClosedXml at codeplex http://closedxml.codeplex.com/

Comment: Try with closedxml.codeplex.com it's very simple and based on open xml standard.